# Linux - Copying a large number of files with ascending numbers in their labels, but mixed up with other labels

Tags: linux

Student needing Linux Help!
I have a file which contains alot of processed data, the following is a sample:

```
    morp2010_001flinnR.OFDATE.stacov  
    morp2010_001flinnR.OFDATE.TDP     
    morp2010_002flinnR.OFDATE.stacov 
    morp2010_002flinnR.OFDATE.TDP     
    morp2010_003flinnR.OFDATE.stacov  
    morp2010_003flinnR.OFDATE.TDP     
    morp2010_004flinnR.OFDATE.stacov
    morp2010_004flinnR.OFDATE.TDP
```

.....etc

what I am looking to do is to use a shortcut to copy the files that end in TDP and put these into a seperate file, does anyone know how I can do this??

I am using "cat" to join all my TDP files to a seperate file, but instead of typing out:

```
cat morp2010_001flinnR.OFDATE.TDP morp2010_002flinnR.OFDATE.TDP... > TDP FILE
```

I want to be able to do something like

```
cat morp2010_(001-XXX).OFDATE.TDP > TDP FILE
```

Can anyone help!?!
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

```
for i in `seq -w 1 729` ; do cat morp2010_${i}.OFDATE.TDP >> TDP_FILE ; done
```

Run `seq -w 1 20` to get a feeling for what `seq` does. Pick the highest number that you've got in your sequence of files for the `729`. :)

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using [zsh](http://www.zsh.org/) instead of bash. There you can do just:

```
cat morp2010_{001..XXX}.OFDATE.TDP > TDP_FILE
```

(replace XXX with the highest number, which you have to know yourself), or

```
cat morp2010_[0-9]#.OFDATE.TDP > TDP_FILE
```

which will simply pick all numbered files.

Comment: Everytime a zsh fanatic comes out of the woodwork I feel like I should really learn it :) but so many of the little tricks feel like things you'd use too infrequently for me to _learn_. :/